# URL Regex issue, php

Tags: php, regex

I have a URL regex I use (and have used quite frequently). It does me well for finding various URL formats and http protocols. That said, I wouldn't be writing here if all was dandy in Dandyland.

I've encountered a hiccup that my current regex below is causing.

When searching a string for URLs, if a string consists of something like `example...see` it will treat it as a URL. There can be any number of periods, however it only pulls the last 3 characters after the last period.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Example:

```
$string = "Here's a url, hello.com. But this...shouldn't show.";

$url_regex = "/((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_\-~@\(\)\%]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&#%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?/i";

preg_match_all($url_regex, $string, $urls);

return $urls;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that you had added a period within the allowed characters which meant there could be more than one consecutive periods. Also `\b` is important when you're dealing with inline searches.

```
\b((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-]*)\.([a-z]+){2,3}(\:[0-9])?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_\-~@\(\)\%]?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_-][a-z0-9;:@&#%=+\/\$_-]*)?(#[a-z_-][a-z0-9+\$_-]*)?\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6rZ9nFozha5YYa_c)

Edit: Updated the answer to ignore matches like example.c

Comment: Thanks. Getting this error on test... `preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: `$string = "Here's a url, hello.com. But this...shouldn't show.";

    $url_regex = "/\b((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-]*)\.([a-z]+)(\:[0-9])?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_\-~@\(\)\%]?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_-][a-z0-9;:@&#%=+\/\$_-]*)?(#[a-z_-][a-z0-9+\$_-]*)?\b/i";

    preg_match_all($url_regex, $string, $urls);

    echo $urls[0][0];`

prints `hello.com`

For some reason I'm unable to type multiline code in comments...

Comment: Forgot the beginning `/` and finishing `/i` :)

Comment: Ah! Excitement of finding a solution.. :)

Comment: Question... it now finds "urls" such as `example.c`...anyway to have it so there has to be at least 2 characters after the period - max 3 characters?

Comment: Good catch.. I've edited the answer to ignore such matches.

Answer (score 0):

Following code solve your issue. I have test at my end.

```
$string = "Here's a url, hello.com. But this...shouldn't show.";

$url_regex = "/((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-]+?)\.([a-z]{2,3})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_\-~@\(\)\%]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&#%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?/i";

preg_match_all($url_regex, $string, $urls);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use https and http with urls in the string.

```
$string = "this is my website http://example.com and this is my friend website https://pqr.com etc, this...shouldn't show";

$regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```